# Optimize hundreds of ItemizedOverlay<Overlayitem> using OSMdroid

Tags: android, performance, android-mapview, osmdroid

I'm using `OSMdroid` to display offline maps. I'm trying to overlay`ItemizedOverlay` onto my mapview. And I'm able to achieve this. But the problem is I 've over a hundred(s) of items that need to be overlayed. I'm getting the data from network.

Since the number of items are too much the mapview can't handle too much data, and its slows the app down and is ANR pops most of the times. To avoid this I'm using points only related to visible screen to check it the point is in the visible screen, yes works to some extent. But the computational complexity is too much, as I'm using a single loop to compute which might take `O(n2)`.

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas,MapView mapview,boolean shadow) {
        try {

             for(int i=0;i<mItemList.size();i++) {
                    GeoPoint currGeo = mItemList.get(i).getPoint();
                    Point newPoint = new Point();
                    final Rect viewportRect = new Rect();
                    mapview.getProjection().toPixels(currGeo, newPoint);
                    viewportRect.set(mapview.getProjection().getScreenRect());
                    if(viewportRect.contains(newPoint.x, newPoint.y)){
                        super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I optimize this snippet or, is there any other approaches where I can optimize, the pan scroll zoom of mapview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "cache" the computationally expensive part of toPixels(). When you set the location on your `Item` you should also call:

```
mProjectedPoint = mapview.getProjection().toProjectedPixels(latitude, longitude, null);
```

and store that value in your `Item` for later use. When you want to get the pixel location of your `Item` you can call

```
Point finalPoint = mapview.getProjection().toPixelsFromProjected(mProjectedPoint, null);
```

The `toPixelsFromProjected` call is much faster than calling `toPixels` every time.

However you also have another option - you can get the map's bounding box (which is in lat/long coordinates) and just check to see if your item's location is in the bounding box.

Note that all of these solutions however only determine if the item's center point is in the screen. The actual drawable portion of your item (for example if it is an icon) is larger than just a single point.

Comment: These are some good pointers. Although usage of any of these still involves atleast a loop, which in my case would run for long time as I've around 700items to display.

Comment: A final option if you really want to get fancy is a spatial database. Then you can query the DB just for items in a certain area.

Comment: Can I write `Overlayitems` in the nearby or closeby region with just numbers on icon heads as 3,10 or something when zoomed out? And when the user zooms in he can see all he split icons. Can you help me with grouping of nearby items when zoomed out?

Answer (score 1):

> "Can I write Overlayitems in the nearby or closeby region with just
>   numbers on icon heads as 3,10 or something when zoomed out? And when
>   the user zooms in he can see all he split icons. Can you help me with
>   grouping of nearby items when zoomed out?"

=> What you describe seems to be marker clustering. That's a good solution when you have a lot of markers inside the view.

OSMBonusPack provides a [Marker Clustering](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_3) system.

Comment: Could have a look at this as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449411/mapview-populate-itemizedoverlay-periodically-android